# Add value for variable in existing yaml file using python

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

**Input.yml:**

```
version: "3.2"
Animal:
  mamal:
    wild:
      - Tiger
      - Lion
    Pet:
      - Dog
      - Cat
  Bird:
    wild:
      - Peacock
      - Ostrich
    Pet:
      - Parrot
      - Dove
Fish:
  Sea:
    - Shark
    - whale
```

Need to add some more values for the pet variable in the Bird section

Python Code I am trying :

```
import yaml

with open ('input.yml', 'r') as read_file:
    contents = yaml.safe_load_all(read_file)
    contents1=list(contents)
    for k in contents1:
        if 'Animal' in contents1[k]:
            contents1['Bird']['Pet'].append(['Duck','swan'])
```

Anyone, please help how to update the YAML files using python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the **`extend()`** function to extend the list of interest. 
You can access the `Animal > Bird > Pet` list by using:

```
contents['Animal']['Bird']['Pet']
```

Here is some example code that:

- `safe_load` the `input.yml` file into the `contents` variable
- `extend` the list of interest as descibed above
- write to a **new** yaml file called `output.yml`
- use `sort_keys=False` to preserve the **same order** as original file.

#### Code:

```
import yaml

# Read the YAML file
with open ('input.yml', 'r') as read_file:
    contents = yaml.safe_load(read_file)

# Update the Animal > Bird > Pet list    
contents['Animal']['Bird']['Pet'].extend(['Duck','Swan'])

# Write the YAML file with sort_keys=False to retain same order
with open('output.yml', 'w') as write_file:
    yaml.dump(contents, write_file, sort_keys=False)
```

#### output.yml:

```
version: '3.2'
Animal:
  mamal:
    wild:
    - Tiger
    - Lion
    Pet:
    - Dog
    - Cat
  Bird:
    wild:
    - Peacock
    - Ostrich
    Pet:
    - Parrot
    - Dove
    - Duck
    - Swan
Fish:
  Sea:
  - Shark
  - whale
```

### Note:

If you wish to just update the `input.yml` file, then just write to that file instead of `output.yml`